# why current is same through each resistance connected in series?

Tags: electric-current

If two resistances R1 and R2 are connected in series then they have different potential difference across their ends say V1 and V2. Now according to ohm's law V=IR, we calculate current through both resistances i.e. I1 = V1/R1 and I2 = V2/R2. My question is that V1 and V2 are different, R1 and R2 are different then how can I1 and I2 can be same???

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation for help in typesetting formulas and ACuriousMind's link for an answer to your question. If the linked thread does not answer your question, please edit your question explaining what you did not find satisfactory there.

Comment: The current in series is the same basically because there are "no leaks" of charge and charge doesn't "pile up", so that the amount of charge that goes through one resistor in some time also goes through the second resistor, then use current is "rate of charge movement."

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not the same if $R_1$ is not equal to $R_2$ but THAT DOES NOT IMPLY that $I_1$ should not be equal to $I_2$. For example, $V_1 = 10$, $V_2$ = 20, $R_1 = 5$, $R_2 = 10$ will give the current through both the resistors to be $I = 2A$

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that V1 and V2 are different, R1 and R2 are different
>   then how can I1 and I2 can be same???

Ohm's Law:

$$V_1 = I_1 R_1$$

$$V_2 = I_2 R_2$$

Let $I_1 = I_2 = I$ and then

$$V_1 = I \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

$$V_2 = I \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Clearly, if $R_1 \ne R_2$, then $V_1 \ne V_2$ even though $I_1 = I_2$